# Java SQL access row data

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I wrote a Java app in which users can login/register. This is working already.
But somehow when I tried coding the logic to check if the user already exists I get an error over error.

This is my code:

```
public static void checkRegister(String mail) {

        try {
            // create a mysql database connection

            Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, user, passwordDB);

              // the mysql insert statement
              String query = "SELECT COUNT(email) mailc, email from users where users.email = \"" + mail + "\"";

              // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
              PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

              // execute the preparedstatement
              preparedStmt.execute();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception!");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I tried using `preparedStmt.getResultSet().getInt("mailc")` but it doesnt work.

**example mail not registered yet**:

[image: example mail not registered yet]

**example mail already registered**:

[image]

My aim is to check if mailc is > 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **AS** with `Count(c) AS col` like this :

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(email) AS mailc, email from users ....";
```

I suggest to use `?` of PreparedStatement instead, to avoid any SQL Injection. So your query should look like this:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(email) mailc, email from users where users.email =?";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString(1, mail);
```

To get the results you have to use a ResultSet:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(email) AS mailc, email from users where users.email =?";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString(1, mail);

ResultSet result = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
while (result.next()) {
   int count = result.getInt("mailc");
   String email = result.getString("email");
}
```

Comment: He is already using `PrepapredStatement` , just that his syntax is wrong

Comment: yes, i know @YoungMillie what did you mean? i don't get you

Comment: You are doing so many editing, at the time I commented, you said he should use `PrepapredStatement` which he was already using. Now that you have edited, everything is okay now.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I changed it in my code. But how can I check the value col "mailc"? `preparedStmt.getResultSet().getInt("mailc")´ seems not to work

Comment: @piguy did you use **AS** you forgot the AS in your query `COUNT(email) AS mailc`

Comment: Yes, I did. The SQL is not the problem I think - it also works in SQL console on phpmyadmin

Comment: @piguy check my edit you have to use ResultSet to get results

Comment: ResultSet result = preparedStmt.execute(); gives me an error: cannot convert from boolean to ResultSet

Comment: sorry @piguy it should be `executeQuery` and not `execute`

Comment: @piguy If you find the answer is correct or helpful, always upvote as people make effort to answer the questions. So please be kind enough to appreciate the efforts.

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, I find it very strange. I do not understand why people downvote without proper reasoning or they are unable to come up with a coherent reasoning for the downvote. It is high time the moderators or the think tank team should cease the downvote option to all the users as it is being misused.

Comment: they want to be the better, but this is not the short way, thank you any way @user75ponic i appreciate it

Comment: I didn't downvote his answer! I marked it as the correct answer. I didn't know my job was to upvote it as well - thought that was more the "viewers" job. Thanks for teaching but don't rage that fast and do not say false facts. @user75ponic

Comment: @piguy Where was the rage and what are the false facts? When did I say the false facts?

Comment: @user75ponic This was dedicated to YCF "I do not understand why people downvote without proper reasoning "

Comment: RE: *You have to use `AS`* Not quite. While using "AS" may be more intuitive, it is not technically *required*. The original syntax was  fine: `select column columnAlias, ...`.

Answer (score 2):

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

Your code may work, the statement is not perfect but working. Can you provide the exeption and we will solve it?
or you can Try Using ' instead of " in your QUERY

Comment: Code above is working - my question is how can I work with the result to get the value from column "mailc"

Comment: Adding preparedStmt.getResultSet().getInt("mailc") gives me nullPointerException

Comment: resultSet = preparedStmt.executeQuery

Comment: can your explain your comment? I want to hear which game? I am trying to solve it without eclipse here.

Comment: the system will detect that he was asking for "ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);" you also saw it. I want thumbs up to mine answer

Comment: Actually this answer isn't so great. When you have code, then format it accordingly. You should also explain why "that code isn't" perfect. And believe me: downvoting other answers is **not** a helpful pattern. Provide quality answers; then reputation flows in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a little guesswork here: you want to check if `users` table already has at least one user with that Email address, and that query will always operate on one given address, not on a list of addresses.

You may want to consider rethinking your query on this one: you want to check if the value exists, yet you ask your database to count how many emails there are. It that particular example this may be fine, because there would be only one such user or no users at all. But in more complex use cases you would actually force your database into doing more work that it should, and that will hit your application performance.

I would suggest that correct query you should use is actually this one:

```
select case when
  exists (select 1 from users where mail = ?)
  then 1 else 0 end as answer
from dual //this is a synthetic table which some DB vendors need.
          //that whole line can be removed if your DB vendor doesn't require it.
```

And respective Java code is:

```
void checkRegistered(String email) {
  initDriver();
  // note the try block below: it will close all resources you have allocated
  try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(uri, credentials.name, credentials.pwd);
       PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
       ResultSet result = st.executeQuery()) {
    if (result.next() && result.getInt("answer") == 1) {
      //do here whatever you do when user is invalid.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - exactly what I needed and tried to do. This works nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code as such:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(email) mailc, email from users where users.email =?";

// create the mysql insert preparedstatement
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString(1,mail);
// execute the preparedstatement
preparedStmt.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I changed it in my code. But how can I check the value col "mailc"? `preparedStmt.getResultSet().getInt("mailc")´ seems not to work